# Parse JSON file in PHP and insert into SQL ----

Tags: php, sql, json, parsing, insert

So I have been doing my research and no method seems to parse my file correctly. I have tried these two codes, my data is being inserted into sql however it is inserted 3 times with the first insertion being fine while the other 2 are blank. Here is my JSON file and code:

JSON:

```
   [
  {
    "Comments": {
      "Manufacturer": "--E", 
      "Model": "----- -----  ----", 
      "BIOSFamily": "---", 
      "BIOSDate": --/--/---8", 
      "SerialNumber": "---------"
    }
  }, 
   {
    "#ComputerSystem.v1-----------ystem": {
      "/redfish/v1/Systems/1/": {
        "AssetTag": "                                ", 
        "Bios": {
          "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/systems/1/bios/"
            }, 
            "BiosVersion": "U----------------)", 
            "Boot": {
          "BootSourceOverrideMode": "-----y", 
          "BootSourceOverrideTarget": "None", 
          "BootSourceOverrideEnabled": "Disabled", 
          "BootSo-----------arget@Redfish.AllowableValues": [
            "None", 
            "Cd", 
            "Hdd", 
            "Usb", 
            "Utilities", 
           "Diags", 
           "BiosSetup", 
            "Pxe", 
           "UefiShell"
          ]
```

Code:

```
<?php

 $connect = mysqli_connect("reserve1", 
"root", "","server_31");

 $filename = "-----.json";

 $data = file_get_contents($filename);

 $array = json_decode($data, true);

 foreach($array as $row)
    {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO servers (Model, 
    Manufacturer, BIOSFamily, 
       BIOSDate, 
    SerialNumber)  VALUES 
    ('".$row["Comments"]["Model"]."' , 
    '".$row["Comments"] 
     ["Manufacturer"]."',
   '".$row["Comments"] 
  ["BIOSFamily"]."','".$row["Comments"] 
   ["BIOSDate"]."','".$row["Comments"] 
   ["SerialNumber"]."')";
        mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
       }




    echo "Data in";

   ?>
```

ERROR:" Notice: Undefined index: Comments "

other forloops i have tried are:

```
foreach($data as $Comments)
{
    $sql =" INSERT INTO 
'servers'('Manufacturer','Model', 
'BIOSFamily','BIOSDate', 
'SerialNumber'), VALUES('{$Comments- 
   >Manufacturer}', '{$Comments- 
   >Model}',  
    '{$Comments->BiosFamily}', 
    '{$Comments->BiosDate}',
                 '{$Comments- 
   >SerialNumber}')";

    }
```

ERROR:" Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in"

To reiterate: the first method does get my info onto sql but does so 3 times with the last 2 entries being blank. The second method does not insert anything into my table.

---

EDIT:

so i tried vardump, using the file itself all i got was NULL, copy and pasting the contents and labeling it $json= ' content ' in the script  i get..

```
 C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Reserve1\newtry\NEWJSONP.php:16:
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'Comments' => 
        object(stdClass)[2]
         public 'Manufacturer' => string 'HPE' (length=3)
          public 'Model' => string '-------------' (length=20)
          public 'BIOSFamily' => string '---' (length=3)
          public 'BIOSDate' => string '--/--/----' (length=10)
          public 'SerialNumber' => string '-------' (length=10)
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Reserve1\newtry\NEWJSONP.php:17:
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'Comments' => 
        array (size=5)
          'Manufacturer' => string '---' (length=3)
          'Model' => string '------ ----------' (length=20)
          'BIOSFamily' => string '---' (length=3)
          'BIOSDate' => string '--/--/----' (length=10)
          'SerialNumber' => string '-------' (length=10)
```

Comment: hello, have you try to `var_dump($array)`?
EDIT: Maybe it's a mistake but in your json it misses a closing `]`

Comment: That's not valid JSON, but if it were: `foreach($array[0] as $row)`

Comment: sorry i missed the " ] ". I will try that you said right now.

Comment: Three times with the last two rows being blank? You are going to have to show us the content of the json, because what you've shown, and what you describe is the error ... don't align.

Comment: I have added the entire JSON file i am attempting to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply index in your `foreach` loop the first item since *$array* object maintains *Comments* only in first position. See 0 index from `var_dump` output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Comments' => 
    array (
      'Manufacturer' => '--E',
      'Model' => '----- -----  ----',
      'BIOSFamily' => '---',
      'BIOSDate' => ' --/--/-- - 8 ',
      'SerialNumber' => '---------',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    '#ComputerSystem.v1-----------ystem' => 
  ...
```

Therefore, iterate through the *Comments* array and use parameterization for readability:

```
$connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// PREPARED STATEMENT
$sql = "INSERT INTO servers (Model, Manufacturer, BIOSFamily, BIOSDate, SerialNumber)
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

// INDEX FIRST ITEM AT 0
foreach($array[0] as $row) { 

    $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);

    // BIND PARAMETERS (NO COMMENTS INDEX)
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $row["Model"], 
                               $row["Manufacturer"],
                               $row["BIOSFamily"],
                               $row["BIOSDate"],
                               $row["SerialNumber"]);

    // EXECUTE STATEMENT
    $result = $stmt->execute();    
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! although I did not use your method, you helped me understand what i w as doing wrong. I took out the [comments] part on my script and it works perfect! The vardump and your explanation helped me understand it. Thank you again so much!

Comment: Great! Glad to help. I do hope though you are using parameterization (industry best practice with SQL at application layer like PHP).

Comment: i am a newbie but i will educate myself on that matter immediately